# Have a reusable modal component in Angular 8

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

I'm using Angular 8 with ng-boostrap 5.2.2.
I would like to have a reusable modal component that :

1. When clicking on a image in the modal close it and return me the value of the image
2. Be able to call the open modal function from the parent component that I can do a (onclick) on the element I want

I'm able to do this from the child component but not the parent.

What I've did so far :

`champion-modal-component.html` (child)

```
<ng-template #mymodal let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Bootstrap Modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.close('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="selected">
            <img (click)="getSelectedChampion('aatrox')" class="selected-image" src="../../../../../assets/champions/aatrox.png" alt="aatrox" title="aatrox">
            <img (click)="getSelectedChampion('ahri')" class="selected-image" src="../../../../../assets/champions/ahri.png" alt="ahri" title="ahri">
            <img (click)="getSelectedChampion('akali')" class="selected-image" src="../../../../../assets/champions/akali.png" alt="akali" title="akali">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" (click)="modal.close('Close click')">
            Close
        </button>
    </div>
</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" (click)="open(mymodal)">
    Open My Modal
</button>
```

`champion-modal-component.ts` (child)

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-champion-modal',
  templateUrl: './champion-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./champion-modal.component.scss']
})
export class ChampionModalComponent implements OnInit {

  championSelected = '';

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  open(content: any) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' });
  }

  getSelectedChampion(champion: string) {
    console.log('champion: ', champion);
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
    this.championSelected = champion;
  }

}
```

`champion-suggestion-component.html` (parent)

```
<!-- I WOULD LIKE THIS and not use a button in the child -->
 <img (click)="openModal()" class="suggestion-image"
                src="../../../../../assets/champions/aatrox.png" alt="aatrox" title="aatrox">    

<app-champion-modal></app-champion-modal>
```

Is this doable with a modal service or with a EventEmitter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did this with a service :

`champion-modal.component.html` (child)

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Select a Champion</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.close('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    <div class="search-container">
    <div class="image-container">
        <div *ngFor="let image of championImages" class="medium-name-circle">
            <img (click)="getSelectedChampion(image.value)" class="medium-name-image"
                src="../../../../../assets/champions/{{image.value}}.png" alt="{{image.value}}"
                title="{{image.viewValue}}">
            <div class="text">{{image.viewValue}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`champion-modal.component.ts` (child)

```
constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal, private modalService: ChampionModalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getSelectedChampion(champion: string) {
    this.activeModal.close();
    this.championSelected = champion;
    this.modalService.getSelectedChampion(this.championSelected);
  }
```

`champion-modal.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ChampionModalComponent } from './champion-modal.component';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChampionModalService {

  // Observable string sources
  private componentMethodCallSource = new Subject<any>();

  // Observable string streams
  componentMethodCalled$ = this.componentMethodCallSource.asObservable();

  roleSelected = '';
  teamSelected = '';

  constructor(private modal: NgbModal) { }

  open() {
    this.modal.open(ChampionModalComponent, { size: 'lg' });
  }

  getSelectedChampion(champion: string) {
    this.componentMethodCallSource.next({
      championName: champion,
      role: this.roleSelected,
      team: this.teamSelected
    });
  }
}
```

`champion-suggestion.component.html` (parent)

```
<img (click)="openModal(role, 'yourTeam')" class="suggestion-image"
                src="../../../../../assets/champions/aatrox.png" alt="aatrox" title="aatrox">
```

`champion-suggestion.component.ts` (parent)

```
constructor(private modalService: ChampionModalService) {
    // Callback of the modal
    this.modalService.componentMethodCalled$.subscribe(
      (parameters) => {
        this.setSelectedChampion(parameters.role, parameters.championName, parameters.team);
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setSelectedChampion(role: string, champion: string, team: string) {
    if (team === 'yourTeam') {
      this.yourTeamRole[role] = champion;
    }
    if (team === 'enemyTeam') {
      this.enemyTeamRole[role] = champion;
    }
  }

  openModal(role: string, team: string) {
    this.modalService.roleSelected = role;
    this.modalService.teamSelected = team;
    this.modalService.open();
  }
```

I have the `Circular dependency detected` warning can I avoid it ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is the `@Output()`.

While using this, you should be able to return a value or call a method on the parent component when closing the child.

Child:

```
// ts
@Output() close = new EventEmitter<any>();

// html
<div (click)="close.emit(value)"></div>
```

Parent:

```
// html
<child-el (close)="functiontoCall($event)"></child-el>

// ts
functiontoCall(event: any) {
  console.log(event);
  this.closeChild(); // hypthetical function to close the child
}
```

You can adapt this code to return the value of the image when clicking on it.
In your case the child is the image component and the parent is the container of those images.